# Remove field: if field exist in SQL table

Tags: sql

I want to try remove field from the mysql table
I have one table like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `seating_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and I want to remove field `seating _no` from table using SQL
here is the query

`ALTER TABLE team DROP seating_no;`
its working. but second time this field is not exist and i want to check again if exist then remove other wish IGNORE how can its possible using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN column_name
```

If exists

```
if exists(select * from sys.columns 
        where Name = N'columnName' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tableName'))
begin
-- Column Exists
end
```

Comment: No Not Like this...table already created and having some data... i just want to check column exist then remove it other wise ignore query